# Sufficient conditions for non-convex constrained optimization (KKT)

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to solve an inequality-constrained minimization problem. My objective and constraints are infinitely differentiable but not necessarily convex.

I found exactly 1 point $\mathbf{x}^{*}$ that satisfies the [KKT necessary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions). **To make sure this point is a minimizer, is it sufficient to show that $\nabla^2\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}^{*}, \mathbf{\lambda})$ is PSD, or do I need something stronger?**

I tried doing some reading about this online but a lot of sources I see focus on the case where the objective and constraints are convex. The ones that don't go over my head with discussion about tangent cones and different types of constraint qualification, terms that I haven't encountered before.

Comment: It is more involved than that. However, if you know that there is a minimiser (not always easy to establish) **and** the active gradients are linearly independent, then $x^*$ must be the minimiser.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! Do you a reference for this?
Also, just to make sure I understand:
existence of minimizer + active gradients are linearly independent + $x^{*}$ satisfies KKT necessary conditions => $x^{*}$ is a minimizer?

Comment: Well, if you know that exactly one point satisfies the KKT necessary conditions **and** you know a minimiser exists then that must be that point.

Comment: Maybe https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande311/lecture07.pdf

Comment: The geometric idea is straightforward, but the mathematical expression awkward.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! 
If I'm not mistaken, I think Wikipedia also suggests that $x^*$ is a local minimum if $s^{\intercal} \nabla^2_{xx} \mathcal{L}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*}) s \geq 0$ for vectors $s$ that satisfy some equation (see link). If I show $\nabla^2 \mathcal{L}(x^{*}, \lambda^{*})$ is PSD (so the inequality holds for all vectors $s$), then am I done?
 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Second-order_sufficient_conditions

Comment: It is a bit too involved for a comment, and I am fairly sure Yinyu addresses the issue. I would expect that $L_{xx}$ needs to be strictly positive definite on a certain space for sufficiency to hold, not just PSD.

Comment: @copper.hat If I show $L_{xx}$ at $x^{*}$ is PD everywhere, then $L_{xx}$ at $x^{*}$ is PD on the subspace Yinyu mentions (slide 21 and 23)?

Comment: This might be a little easier https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter2.pdf.

Comment: Are the active gradients at $x^*$ linearly independent?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the link! Yes, the gradients at $x^{*}$ are linearly independent. But, from the link, it looks like LICQ (linearly independent constraint qualification) is not needed as long as $L_{xx}$ at $x^{*}$ is positive definite?

Comment: Yes, sorry a bit slow today. If the KKT conditions hold (and the point is feasible) and $L_{xx} >0$ then $x^*$ is a strict local minimum. Theorem 2.21.

Comment: @copper.hat No worries! Thanks for confirming!!

Comment: Copper.hat, it's needed that all  feasible point satisfies a constraint qualification, and not only the KKT one. I went here to clarify some confusions done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something stronger is needed. The difficulty with your question is that it's possible that global minimizers do not satisfy KKT, and yet there exists one point satisfying the KKT conditions. For example, the problem
\begin{align}
\text{min }  &  -x^2+x^3 \\
\text{s.t. } & x^3(x+1)^3\leq  0
\end{align} has only one global minimizer and only one KKT point, the origin, which is not the global minimizer. This is because minimizers require a constraint qualification to satisfy the KKT conditions. In order for your assertion to be true, you require that all points, and not only one, of the feasible set also satisfy a constraint qualification, like MFCQ. In such context, the result is true because if your problem admits a minimum since every point satisfies MFCQ, this global minimum must satisfy KKT. The global minimizer satisfies KKT, and If your problem has only one KKT point, that KKT point must be the global minimizer. Now you could ask me:

> It's really required that all points satisfy a constraint qualification?

Yes, it's needed. That's because even if only one point does not satisfy a constraint qualification, the global minimizer might be that point, and such a point might not be a KKT one. Now, you could turn back to me again and ask me:

> What about PSD? Does it help?

No, it does not help at all. The PSD says that your point is a local minimizer, and being a local minimizer does not imply that it is the global minimizer, since you don't know whether your problem has only one local minimizer.

You could ask:

> Is there a solution?

Yes, you need to test whether your point is the only one satisfying a genuine optimality condition, i.e., a condition that holds for every local minimizer of your problem. In such a case, I would test if there exists another point such that $$\text{it does not satisfy MFCQ at x or the KKT conditions holds at that point x}$$ or, roughly and in symbols, $$x \text{ is  KKT or MFCQ does not hold at } x.$$ This last condition holds for every optimal point and being that point unique, this point must be a global minimizer, whenever it exists.

Now you could ask me:

> What are constraint qualifications?

That type of question is exactly what I have done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339583/a-proper-definiton-for-constraint-qualification-for-nonlinear-programming). I am not aware of a precise definition of constraint qualification. I, and as far I know only myself, would assume that a constraint qualification is any mathematical assertion/proposition that implies Guignard constraint qualification. Quite artificial, but extremely precise, since I would bet that there will never be one constraint qualification that does not imply Guignard constraint qualification, due to [Gould and Tolle result](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0120021?journalCode=smjmap).

Comment: Thanks! Your post clears up a lot of confusion that I had on the matter.

Does this mean that the global solution may not necessarily satisfy KKT conditions?
And can I interpret KKT as a method of finding local minima among points that satisfy the constraint qualification (CQ)? KKT misses points that do not satisfy the CQ, so I need to handle those points separately.

Comment: Yes, you can think of KKT as a way of finding a solution that satisfies a constraint qualification, but note that there are problems that do not meet MFCQ in any feasible point, but, yes, you got the point! To optimize the problem, you need to deal with nonqualified points separately.