# Lagrange multipliers: What types of constraints work?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose we to maximize $x+y$ subject to $x^2+y^2=3$. Can we use Lagrange multiplier for this?

It seems we can since the tangency condition holds in this case. I have generally only seen functions where the constraint is a plane and the objective function is quasi-convex. Here, the function is weakly convex but the constraint is less familiar to me.

So for what types of constraints does Lagrange work?

Comment: Usually you want the constraint to define a convex set; here it defines a circle which is not convex.

Comment: Yes, you can use here the method of Lagrange multipliers. You can probably use the bordered Hessian to check which extreme point(s) you've calculated.

Comment: Any kind of constraint with continuous partial derivatives works I think. The only point where lagrange multipliers struggle is if you're unlucky and have that the gradient of the constraint is 0 at the extreme point you're trying to find. In that case the Lagrange multiplier method will miss those points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrange multipliers rule holds almost everywhere. Basically, whenever the constraints satisfies a constraint qualification, the Lagrange multipliers rule holds. In the general case, the conditions are also called the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions. For example, whenever any of the regularity conditions displayed in the Wikipedia website holds, the KKT conditions also hold, see the [regularity conditions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)). In your case, all regularity conditions are equivalent (just one active constraint). Basically, whenever the constraint has a nonzero derivative, the KKT conditions hold. What to do when the derivative is zero? After you tested all KKT points, test whether there is a functional value smaller than other ones associated with a zero derivative of the constraint. See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366991/sufficient-conditions-for-non-convex-constrained-optimization-kkt/4367285#4367285). In your case, I'll tell you in advance that the derivative never vanishes at feasible points.